# What is the practical difference between nebelah and terefah?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, slaughter-shochet-shecht, lomdus, chulin-tractate

The second mishna on [Chullin 32a](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=31&daf=32&format=pdf) explains that if an animal is rendered invalid by any death which does not occur through proper ritual slaughter it is *nebelah* while if it is rendered invalid for some other reason it is *terefah*.  My question is: what are the consequences of an animal having one of these statuses versus the other?  You can't eat it either way, obviously; are there differences in what benefit you can derive from it?  What are they, and which is the more severe disqualification?

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8513/does-an-improperly-slaughtered-animal-render-the-shochet-impure

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As far as I know, the above answer is correct. A *neveilah* conveys ritual impurity, while a *treifa* does not; as per the *gemura* in [Niddah on 42b](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=42b&format=pdf) (about 3/4 of the way down the *daf*), which makes a *drasha* from the *pasuk* in Vayikra 22:8.

Comment: Adam, Welcome to Judaism.SE, and thanks very much for the clear citation! I look forward to seeing you around.

Answer (score 4):

As the other answers stated, the main difference between נבילה וטריפה is the טומאה. However, there are also other differences, such as אותו ואת בנו (see שמלה חדשה טו); in שלחן ערוך פב where ביצת טריפה is אסור but ביצת נבילה is not; and (lamely) someone who makes a vow נדר not to benefit from one but left the other alone. These are found all over שמלה חדשה for a quick summary see there, [20:6](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=87).
One that he does not mention there is also found in Baba Kama (7:2, 7:5), where a thief must pay double כפל for טריפה (because it is a שחיטה) but not for נבילה (because it isn't).

Answer (score 2):

A *neveilah* is *tamei* (ritually impure); a *treifa* isn't. Benefit is permitted either way.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: Well the fact that it's tameh isn't a practical difference, rather the fact that it's mitameh.

Comment: @BaalShemotTovot I'm trying really hard to think of a nafka mina of its being tamei.

Answer (score 2):

> Nebelah: An animal that has died a natural death or was killed not in
>   accordance with the jewish ritual lawnatural death is called "nebelah"
>   (carcas). (Bechoros, 3a)
>
> Terefah: An animal afflicted with an organic disease or disability
>   (eg. the removal of a certain portion of the knee) (Chulin, 42a)

A first-born-Nebelah can have kedushat-Bechor and needs to be redeemed from a Kohen. If it is terefah it loses its Bechor-status and doesn't need redeeming.

According to Rav Hisda, if, when it died, a non-Jew owned any of the parts of the Nebelah that would render the animal treif if that part was missing (eg. windpipe), then the animal is unfit to be a Bechor, and doesn't need to be redeemed. (Bechoros, 3a)