# Is Halal Meat Kosher?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, gentiles, slaughter-shochet-shecht, islam

Muslims slaughter a Cow by saying "Bismillah, Allahu Akbar" meaning : "In the name of Allah , Allah is Great"" and follow the [Zabiha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zabiha#Islamic_slaughtering) (shechita) procedure to make it Halal.

Some salient point of the [Zabiha procedure](http://muslimmatters.org/2012/06/22/is-kosher-meat-%E1%B8%A5alal-a-comparison-of-the-halakhic-and-shar%CA%BFi-requirements-for-animal-slaughter/#sthash.twAnDEzi.dpuf):

> 1) The animal must be alive when it is slaughtered (hence stunning or
>   other procedures to render the animal unconscious should be avoided).
>
> 2) The animal must be killed with a sharp knife (hence, a blow to the
>   head would render the animal treif and ḥarām).
>
> 3) The knife must cut the neck arteries of the animal: in particular, the trachea,
>   esophagus, cartiod arteries and jugular veins should be cut, while
>   leaving the spinal cord intact.
>
> 4) The blood must be drained out.
>
> 5) There must be minimal harm to the animal – a painless and quick
>   slaughter is required.

Can such meat be considered Kosher?  I have read [here](http://www.judaism-islam.com/can-a-jewproclaim-allah-akbar-before-slaughtering-a-cow/) that the Pe'at Hashulchan by R. Israel Shklover permits a Jewish shochet to say "Allahu Akbar"  without it being a hefsek (interruption), but what about a cow slaughtered by a Muslim?

Answer (score 28):

If a non-Jew slaughters an animal, it is not kosher. ([Mishna Chullin 1:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%97%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%9F_%D7%90_%D7%90) [English on p. 36 of [this .PDF](http://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Chullin.pdf)], [Rambam Shechita 4:11](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%91%22%D7%9D_%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%A9%D7%97%D7%99%D7%98%D7%94_%D7%93_%D7%99%D7%90) [[English translation](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/971830/jewish/Chapter-4.htm)], [Shuchan Aruch YD 2:1](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%99%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%93%D7%A2%D7%94_%D7%91#.D7.A1.D7.A2.D7.99.D7.A3_.D7.90) In fact, I know of no authority who has ever argued on this point.)

Comment: I think I've heard somewhere (can't source it) that in certain circumstances, given a choice between halal meat and non-halal meat, a Jew should chose the halal meat. Is that made up in my mind, or is that a real opinion?

Comment: @Daniel I've never heard of it. If the Shochet wasn't a Jew, then there isn't much to talk about at all in terms of its kashrut. Perhaps the advantage of hallal meat is that you know it's a kosher species at least. I've heard that it's better to eat nevela than pork when forced to (no source though).

Comment: Interesting. You might want to add to this answer that the requirements for knife sharpness and shape, for checking the lungs, and for using only one cut are more stringent for kosher meat than for halal meat. http://muslimmatters.org/2012/06/22/is-kosher-meat-%E1%B8%A5alal-a-comparison-of-the-halakhic-and-shar%CA%BFi-requirements-for-animal-slaughter/

Comment: I would say @Daniel is correct. According to the Rambam (Shechita 4:11) a non Jew's shechita is problematic only mid'rabbanan if he is not an idol worshipper. Therefore, although Halal meat is not exactly shechita, one is slightly more likely to miss out on a biblical prohibition with Halal meat than with regular non-kosher meat, even though neither are actually kosher.

Comment: @DovF You mean 4:12? I would emphasize the word _slightly_. Most rishonim argue on the Rambam here, it's not at all clear we paskin like him, and there can be other issues with the shechita as well, such as pegimos on the chalaf (which is certainly a deoraita problem) which I see no way to be meikil on.

Comment: @Ali, For what the Torah says, [see this discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8317329#8317329).

Comment: @Ali, once again, your preference for a TaNa"Ch-based source is offensive in its rejection of our tradition that the Oral Law is part and parcel of THE TORAH.

Comment: @Ali, the Mishnah was _put to writing_ approximately 2000 years ago. It was _not made up of whole cloth_, just put into written form. Furthermore, the Mishnah itself was written long before the birth of Muhammad. It records teacher-to-student transmission of the law GIVEN TO MOSES AT SINAI. This is the CORE of Jewish belief. If you reject that, there is no basis for your question because you will NECESSARILY reject ANY answer provided.

Comment: @DoubleAA, IIRC, camel is considered _halal_, so you could _not_ “know it’s a kosher species at least”.

Answer (score 17):

Normative halacha ([SA YD 2:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x3483), and [Simla Chadasha 2:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=19)) both state unequivocally that the shechita of a non-Jew is forbidden ([biblically](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/623/5323)).
<sub>See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37554/5323) for why I care so much about the Simla Chadasha.</sub>

However, the opinion of the Rambam (mentioned in other answers, *hilchos shechita* in [4:11](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=5&hilchos=29&perek=4&halocha=11&hilite=)-12) is that gentile slaughter is only biblically prohibited when that gentile is an idol-worshiper. If the gentile is not an idol worshiper, the meat will not be forbidden biblically (but will still be forbidden [rabbinically](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/623/5323)). The [Shach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shabbatai_HaKohen) ([YD 2:2](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x3483)) alters the text of the Rambam to say that the slaughter of ***kutim***<sup>1</sup> is only rabbinically prohibited, but that of gentiles in general is biblically forbidden (regardless of their religious practice).

According to mainstream, modern halacha, one may not choose to follow the Rambam in this because he is the only *[Rishon](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3718/5323)* that thinks this way<sup>2</sup> [see related Rambam in שאר אבות הטומאה [ב:י](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=10&hilchos=60&perek=2&halocha=10&hilite=) where the [Raavad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abraham_ben_David) (on that linked page) calls this the Rambam's worst idea ("[סברא](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A1%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90)") ever(!)]
That said, my rebbi told me that when he visited a country (I want to say Bengal but I'm not sure), he found that the Jews living there would eat halal meat, based on this Rambam. Again, this is not normative halacha, but that was their custom.

**As to the procedure itself:** if a Jew would follow all the points mentioned above, plus the Halachos of Shechita (הלכות שחיטה); *and* the animal was not [*treifa*](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/9251/5323), then the meat would be permitted. Saying "Allahu Akbar" before slaughter is not preferred (because that could cause a break between the blessing and the slaughter), but does not invalidate the slaughter. ([SC 19:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=81))

---

<sup>1</sup> *Kutim*, in Jewish law, were converts who converted out of fear. They are considered to be sort of Jewish -- therefore, if Rambam refers to *kutim*, one cannot generalize the law to other gentiles.

<sup>2</sup> See, however, https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/52827/5323.

Comment: I'm not sure where this is mentioned, but I was told that the Rambam holds that while Christianity is avoda zara, Islam is not -- therefore a Muslim shechita would only be derabonon according to the Rambam mentioned above.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the opinion of Rambam that Halal meat generally is kosher or  allowed to eat  for a Jew (if it meets the conditions of Jewish slaughtering, except that a Non-Jew is slaughtering)?

Comment: @Kilise Sort of. According to some interpretations of Rambam, there is no biblical prohibition to eat meat that was slaughtered by a non-idol-worshipper. No other rabbis agree AFAIK, and some say that he doesn't even mean that. Note also that "not biblically prohibited" doesn't mean "permitted;" there is still a rabbinic prohibition involved.

Answer (score 3):

The original question that this was transferred from asked about being in a small community very far away (think Texas or Alaska and the distances between communities in that state) from any source of kosher food (especially meat). He asked if Hallal would be preferable to *regular* non-kosher meat. He also mentioned eating fish, which is why I mentioned getting kosher fish from a regular fish market.

The *hallal* is just as much *neveilah* as any kosher species meat slaughtered by any other non-kosher butcher and just as forbidden. As I explain in [Why is meat only kosher if a Jew slaughters the animal?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81375/why-is-meat-only-kosher-if-a-jew-slaughters-the-animal/81376#81376), even if a non-Jew slaughters under the supervision of Jew who makes sure that everything was done properly, the meat is **still** forbidden as *neveilah*.

Similarly, you would need to check on how to get kosher fish products from a general fish market. One way would be to get kosher fish (fins and scales) and use your onwn (kosher) knife for the clerk to scale and cut the fish.

There are national brands that have a hechsher that you can find in your local supermakets. There are national brands that you can order to be shipped to you if they are not in your local stores.

Google is your friend. I did a search on *Texas ship kosher meat to home* and got a number of links to different stores that will send it to you. Note that since I do not need to do this, I cannot verify the kashrus or quality of any of the stores that have these web sites. When you do a google, you would also get non-Kosher ads as well, so you need to double check who they are and what hechsher they have.

For example

[AviGlatt.com](https://www.aviglatt.com/Pages.asp?PageName=Kosher-Delivery)

> You don't have to live in an area where Aviglatt.com is
>   Aviglatt.com Offers home delivery to get the best food at the best prices to ANYONE ANY WHERE in the U.S.A
>   How it works
>   Sign up, browse our site for your favorite foods,
>   and complete Checkout to place your order.
>   You may place an order up to one week in advance.
>   Order cutoff for next-day is 5 p.m. no shipping on weekend

[New YorkKosherSteaks.com](http://www.nykoshersteaks.com/pages/Shipping.html)

> Shipping
>
> We strongly believe that the best steaks are fresh steaks, so we go to
>   great lengths to ensure that our steaks reach your door without ever
>   being frozen. All of our steaks are packaged in a vacuum-sealed bag
>   allowing for it to retain freshness during the course of shipping. 
>   They are then placed in an insulated box with frozen gel packs to
>   ensure that the meat is kept fresh from our door to yours.
>
> All of our packages are shipped FedEx Ground, Express Saver, Standard
>   Overnight or 2nd Day delivery. We package our shipments to withstand
>   additional shipping time to make sure that they arrive fresh. We do
>   not allow shipments to last longer than 3 days, so if your location is
>   enabled for FedEx Ground, this guarantees that your package will
>   arrive in 3 days at the most.
>
> Because of these conditions, no signature is required for our delivery
>   and they will be left at your door.  If there are specific
>   instructions for your deliveryman, please write them in the comments
>   box on your checkout page. We do not ship over weekends, so orders
>   placed after Thursday at 10 AM EST will ship on the following Monday.
>   Shipping Rates
>
> For FedEx Ground Shipments, we have a flat-rate that is based on
>   weight. For orders under 60 lbs., the cost of shipping is $22, and for
>   packages over 60 lbs., the cost is $42 because we will need to split
>   the package into 2 boxes.  Keep in mind that the shipping weight
>   factors in the frozen gel packs and cooler box that are included in
>   the shipment.
>
> The shipping rates for Express Saver, FedEx 2nd Day and Overnight
>   orders are weight-based. A price is specifically generated for your
>   order and that will be presented during your checkout. The weight of
>   any such item can be found on its detail page.

Comment: One other item to verify when ordering meat - Make sure that the meat has been soaked and salted (koshered) before they deliver it. Most likely, it is, but, it doesn't hurt to check. This is esp. a concern if you won't pick up your order by 3 days (e.g. the 3rd day is Shabbat.) My understanding is that after 3 days the blood congeals and the meat can no longer be koshered.

Comment: @mevaqesh I added the source by pointing to my answer to a previous question which goes into detail about that.

Comment: This answer was posted on another question and merged hither.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Part of the answer applies only to the original question as he stated that he was isolated in Texas and needed to be able to get kosher food. The answer that Halal is like any other neveilah is only part of it. The pointers to where to get kosher meat is for that question and does not apply to this question.

Comment: @sabbahillel thanks for pointing that out.  I've made a small edit that I think addresses the issue; how does it look to you?

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm not sure that anything in this post after the first paragraph is relevant to this question.

Comment: @MonicaCellio No the point of the google was that the original question asked about what to do if there is no kosher products in the small town in Texas where the OP lives and if Hallal could be used instead. It is **not** the same as this question. You should repost the original question with this answer.

Comment: @Shokhet You are correct. I would not have put this answer to the question above. The answer fits to the question that I saw originally.

Comment: @MonicaCellio The question also mentioned fish which is why I had that paragraph in here. Please restore this answer to the actual question as asked. He asked if Hallal was better than other nonKosher meat, not *Is Hallal Kosher*.

Comment: @sabbahillel I am sorry; I was trying to help and made things worse.  I went ahead and [asked a new question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81451/472); please feel free to paste this answer there and delete this one.  If you don't get at least as many upvotes there as here I'll find some way to make it up to you.  I can't just move it, unfortunately.  (The [original question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/81428/472) does not mention fish, BTW, and neither does my new question.  I couldn't find a way to make it fit cleanly.)

Comment: BTW we would have had to anonymize the original question had it remained, which is why I tried to generalize what you said about Google to cast it as an example.  The new question stays farther away from "request for *p'sak*", so specific locations aren't relevant there but you can still offer the advice about getting food from outside one's local community.

Comment: @MonicaCellio OK I will try to make it more general an try to refer to it better

Answer (score 2):

Even if we were to agree that meat slaughtered by Muslims is kosher, they use most of the animal and don't remove nerves.

Answer (score -11):

Since the meat is offered to Allah as it is slaughtered, this food should be considered as food sacrificed to an idol.  We have run into Jews that consider Halal meat fine, but the prohibition on partaking of idol sacrifices is very clear.

Comment: BatyaL, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Can you cite a source for your assumption that Allah is considered an idol by Jewish law? As far as I know, "Allah" is just the Arabic word for "God."

Comment: Also, your information is incorrect. It's not offered to Allah as a sacrifice. It's done in the name of Allah.

Comment: furthermore, Muslims are monotheists who believe in the G-d of Avraham. The word "Allah" means G-d.  It is not an idol.

Comment: In fact, even if a Jew were to say "Allah Akbar" before slaughtering, the meat would be permitted.

Comment: @Shokhet, it wouldn't be a hefsek?

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Correct, which is why you shouldn't say it in between the bracha and the shechita (SC [19:8](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=81)); it would not make the meat prohibited, because even if you did not make a bracha, the meat is still permitted. (tried finding source for that second הנחה; couldn't, will try to post back when I get it)