# Halacha of Shechita

Tags: halacha, jewish-books, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Which Sefer or Sefarim is/are used in practical application of Shechita? General Halacha follows the שלחן ערוך, but does it in all areas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In America, the custom is as the custom of Europe -- to use the sefer [שמלה חדשה](http://hebrewbooks.org/35269), written by [Rabbi Alexander Sender Schor](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%90%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%A1%D7%A0%D7%93%D7%A8_%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%A8) (1673-1737), even though on occasion he will disagree with the שלחן ערוך. Rabbi Schor also wrote תבואת שור (an explanation to Simlah Chadasha) and [בכור שור](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/51017/5323), a commentary on Shas.

(see מטה אשר [commentary to שמלה חדשה] in [1:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=12), especially what he quotes from the דרכי תשובה)

I had heard that the custom in Israel is to use the בית דוד, though some commenters on this answer had heard otherwise.

Comment: All of Europe had the same custom?

Comment: @DoubleAA See the מטה שאר in the link, he says that this is the custom in Russia, Galicia, and הגר (Hungary?)...sounds like a good chunk of Europe to me. My rebbi made it sound like all of it had this custom.

Comment: [הגר is Hungary](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/37799/where-is-the-country-not-the-person)

Comment: Just for the record I got my Kabbala in Israel and reviewing the Simla CHadash once every 30 days was a condition. Also Rabbi Waldman who re-printed the Simla Chadasha lived/worked in Israel so I would say it's the prevalent custom in Israel as well.

Comment: Is the okay for print the english translation, meaning is it meant for public to use free?

Comment: @MosheRabbi I'm not certain that I understand your comment. If you mean Rabbi Loike's translation (which is the only English translation I'm aware of), I'm pretty sure that he includes a license to distribute his translation for free (but I would check to be sure)

Comment: @Shokhet Yep I meant about that! Can you email it to me?

Comment: @eramm may I ask where you got a Kabbalah from?

Answer (score 5):

If you wish to get tested by the Chief Rabbinate of Israel you must be proficient in Tur, Shulchan Aruch with Nosei Kelim.

Rabbi Chaim Lokie in his English Simlah Chadasha (footnote Siman 18) writes that many in Israel are accustomed in the learning of Sefer Beis Dovid.  Rabbi Yehudah Landsman of Monsey would also teach Beis Dovid to his students.

Many in the United States - like Moreinu Rav Eliyahu Ben-Chaim of Yeshiva University - allow you to learn any Sefer that is accepted by Gedolei Yisroel (Tur Shulchan Aruch, Simlah Chadasha, Beis Dovid, etc.).

Comment: Where can one find this English version of the Simlah Chadasha

Comment: You can buy on Lulu.com or see a preview on Google Books.