# Kabbalah/Certification in Shechita in US?

Tags: product-recommendation, hechsher-certification, slaughter-shochet-shecht, united-states

Who can someone go to to get [Kaballah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37705/5323) in Shechita in America?

Comment: I also did not understand the question, so I googled "kaballah in shechita".  Found this

http://www.jta.org/2013/11/21/life-religion/kosher-slaughter-in-the-backyard

Seems to imply "do it yourself shechitah", kosher slaughter in the backyard.  Is this what you are asking?

Comment: Is there a specific kind of Kabbalah in Shechita that you seek?

Comment: @Dennis http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37705/5323

Comment: The Do it yourself is actually quite a problem. Today it is forbidden to eat from shochet who hasn't received kabbala

Comment: 9841, the article that @Dennis linked to mentioned that the DIY people did get kabalah from someone

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/959/759

Comment: A list of specific rabbis will go out of date over time; a better formulation of this question would be "how can I find?".  That way, if there are referral services, professional organizations, etc, people could point to those and you could use that information to find a specific person.

Answer (score 3):

Certification for shechitah is known as a "kabalah", not (directly) related to "Jewish mysticism."

I recall seeing a sign advertising lessons that would culminate in an exam/certification from either [Rabbi Yisroel Belsky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yisroel_Belsky) in Brooklyn (who is on OU Kosher's policy panel), or a name in Lakewood I'm afraid I didn't recognize. At least that's one name for you ...

Comment: AFAIK Rabbi Belsky doesn't give people kabalah...but perhaps I don't know that far :P

Comment: So any other ideas??

Answer (score 2):

[Rabbi Avidan Elkin](http://bisrakosher.com/summer-shehhitah-class-with-rabbi-elkin/) of Hackensack, NJ