# Sefardic and Ashkenazic main halacha book for Even Haezer, Yoreh Deah and Choshen Mishpat?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, mishnah-berurah

Besides the Mishna Berurah (Orach Chaim) for ashkenazim and the Kaf Hahaim (Orah Chaim and parts of Yoreh Deah) for Sefardim, what is used to complete the scope of Shulchan Aruch ?

Comment: The Aruch Hashulchan,as well as the major achronim on the Shulchan Aruch(Pri megadim,Pischei Tshuvah,Dagal Marvavah

Comment: If I recall the Aruch Hashulchan covers the whole SA, but what about the Pri Megadim, Pischei Tshuvah, Dagal Marvavah ?

Comment: The Pischei Tshuvah is on all except Orach Chaim,the Be'er Heitiv is on all.

Comment: Many Sefaradim today, to my knowledge, derive Halakhah LeMa'aseh from Yalqut Yosef which spans all four turim of Shulhhan Arukh.

Comment: No source for saying so and it addresses only _YD_ not the other _turim_, so I'm not posting it as an answer, but: _Chochmas Adam_.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the Sefer Yalkut Yosef written by the current Israeli Chief Rabbi. Although he's Sefardi he quotes all the Shitos!

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

Ashkenazim in America and Europe use the [Simlah Chadasha](http://hebrewbooks.org/35269) for Hilchos Shechita (beginning of Yoreh De'ah), as brought down in the Matteh Asher ([here](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=12)) and in Darkei Teshuva.

(See also [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37555/5323).)

I am told that the custom in Israel is to use the sefer Beis Dovid for these halachos, but I have never seen this brought down inside anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The ba'er heiteiv of course! Written by different authors for different chalakim of shulchan aruch, but long held as authorotive. In fact Rav Shamshon Rafael Hirsch mentioned this work as binding for all jews to learn along with shulchan aruch. Of course latter works have been accepted in orach chayim but none have replaced it on the other chalakim.

Answer (score -1):

For Sefarad, Shulchan Aruch of the Beis Yosef. Ashkenaz use either Rama or Mishna Berurah. The Tur also covers this topic. (Shulchan aruch harav a.k.a Alter Rebbe m'Lubavitch shulchan aruch covers hilchos nida in depth). For Sefardim, the Beis Yosef covers pretty much everything there is to know. As for chassidim (mainly Chabad) the Alter Rebbe covers Chosen Mishpat in depth.

Comment: Thanks but there is nothing contemporary to the Kaf Hahaim or MB ? Also, which parts of the SA the Mappa covers ?

Comment: Kaf Hachaim discusses the Orahch Chayim. Mishna Berurah should have a hilchos nida and kidushin, as well as chosen mishpat. If this is urgent look it up in Kitzur Shulchan Aruch or speak to your Rav if you have an urgent question.

Comment: the Hamappah is based on the Beis Yoseif.

Comment: No this is not urgent. Thank you for your answers. Does the Hamappah and the Rav SA covers all the Shulchan Aruch ?

Comment: What do you mean by Rav Shulchan Aruch? Do you mean Alter Rebbe?

Comment: Yes this is what I mean.

Comment: Hamappah covers some things from the Beis Yoseif but it differs between Sefardim and Ashkenazim. The Shulchan Aruch HaRav is not complete since it got burned during the fire in the city so many hilchos and minhagim are missing from there sadly

Comment: Thanks! Which is the best for Even Haezer then ?

Comment: In my opinion it would be the Tur or Beis Yoseif. But what topic specifically in Even Haezer?

Comment: I am not looking for a particular topic, I just want to know what sefarim I need to cover all the topic. For now, I know I need the SA (for everything), Mishnah Berurah (Orach Chaim, Choshen Mishpat, Nidda and Kiddushin), the Rav SA (Choshen Mishpat), Kaf Hachaim (Orach Chayim), the Hamappah. I do not count the Tur since the SA is based on it.

Comment: Any more questions?

Comment: Alter Rebbe on Choshen Mishpat is far from complete