# What is the bracha on shechita?

Tags: halacha, blessing, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Is there a bracha (blessing) said for shechita (kosher slaughter)? If so, what is the bracha?

Is the blessing said before or after the animal is slaughtered?

Comment: lets say someone forgot to say the bracha ,is it kosher ,see the Rosh,see also the Or Zaruah

Comment: @sam Do you think I should include that in this Q/A set? ....SC talks about it ([19:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=78)), says that it's fine, but if we see that people are being מיקל in it we should קנס them.

Comment: not necessarily ,just thought its an interesting note about Eldad Hadani's shittah that its not kosher

Comment: @sam I might, but maybe not right now.

Comment: Why were you wondering this?

Comment: @DoubleAA http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/48099/5323

Comment: @sam http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50410/5323 ;-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- There is a bracha on shechita, here is the wording:

  > ברוך אתה ה' אלוקינו מלך העולם **אשר קדשנו במצוותיו וציוונו על השחיטה**

  ~ *SA YD [19:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x3518) (see also [Simlah Chadashah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37555/5323) at [19:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=78))*

  - Rambam writes (Hil. Brachos [11:12](http://hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?sefer=2&hilchos=10&perek=11&halocha=12)) that if one slaughters his own קרבן פסח (Pesach offering), he makes a different bracha:

    > אשר קדשנו במצוותיו וציוונו **לשחוט**

    ( *h/t DoubleAA for pointing this Rambam out -- I had never seen it before!* )
- The blessing is said before the animal is slaughtered.

  ~ *SA ibid, SC ibid*

  - The exception to this case is if there is a possible problem with the animal, and it is uncertain whether it is kosher or not (due to טרפות, mostly terminal health problems) -- in that case, the blessing is made **after the shechita and subsequent bedika (inspection)** (*Rama [19:1](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=yd_x3518), SC [19:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=79)*). The shechita, bedika, and bracha should all follow each other without *hefsek* (pause); if there was a pause, then the blessing is not made (*SC [19:2](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=79)*).

    ( *h/t DoubleAA for pointing this out the Rama -- I had never seen it before, and had forgotten what the SC had written about it* )