# Do you have to be able to see to do shechita?

Tags: halacha, see-sight-vision-blind, slaughter-shochet-shecht

In the wake of a [question about *shechita* on a boat](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50973/472) (ok, with a cutlass, but also on a boat), the topic of other unusual *shechita* conditions [came up in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19289571#19289571):

> Can I do it in on a boat? Can I do it on a goat?
>   Can I do it in the rain? Can I do it on a train?
>   In the dark? In a tree?
>   In a car? Shecht, you see? ...
>   - Charles Koppelman

This got me wondering -- *can* you do *shechita* in the dark?  Can a blind man be a *shochet*?

My instinct is "no" because it seems like you would need to visually verify your work, but I'm a city-dweller for whom meat comes in portioned packages wrapped in styrofoam and plastic wrap.  I've never witnessed nor studied *shechita*.  I've heard that it's largely done by feel and being able to see doesn't actually matter.

So: does *halacha* permit sightless *shechita*?  And if it does, is it actually practical to do?

Comment: It is kosher (Mishna Chullin 1:1). I doubt it's very practical.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Simla Chadasha ([*the* book on shechita](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/37555/5323)) rules ([11:1](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=45&hilite=)) that one should not shecht in the dark/at night, because he won't be able to look at the *simanim*, to check whether he did what he needed to do (רוב אחד בעוף רוב שנים בבהמה; most of one "siman" (windpipe/foodpipe) for a bird, most of two "simanim" for an animal). "Dark" is defined as "too dark to see what he's doing," so it will be a little subjective.

However, if one did so, and is able to check the *simanim* afterwards, then the shechita will always be kosher, even if it was done in the dark, or at night-time.
Interestingly, Mateh Asher there (#3) notes that someone who needs glasses to see is also not allowed to slaughter if he's not wearing his glasses -- the above rule doesn't have to do with daytime, or a certain amount of light that is present; it has to do with the ability to see. If someone is unable to check the *simanim* after shechita without his glasses on, then he can't shecht without his glasses.
Another point to note, Mateh Asher also says (#8) that if someone is using an electric lamp ("נר עלעקטר"י"), he needs to have a back up candle, because "פעמים נכבה מעצמו ע"י סבה," "sometimes it will go out for whatever reason." However, my rebbi has noted that there is no longer a need for this, as our electric lights are pretty reliable; as far as I've seen, we don't require a back up candle when shechting at night by electric light, though I've been told that some groups of chasidim are still concerned for this. I have shechted at night by electric light without a candle under my rebbi's supervision.

---

About the blind: Simla Chadasha rules ([1:37](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=35269&st=&pgnum=17)) that someone who is blind "in both eyes" may do shechita, although it should not be done [*lechatchila*](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/702/5323), unless there is someone else observing, or there is a pressing need (שעת הדחק is the same as בדיעבד).
If the particular person is a "מובהק בדעת ויראת ה," and knows the halacha very well, then he can be trusted to check his own shechita, to determine if the shechita was done properly.

Comment: ... <click> 2 minutes, 33 seconds

Comment: @Isaac http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19291571#19291571

Comment: I don't understand the _halacha_ cited in your first paragraph: can't one light a lamp and check the _simanim_? (Likewise, can't he put on his glasses and check them, for the _Mate Asher_?) Is there an immediacy requirement or something?

Comment: @msh210 You raise a good point -- either the case under discussion is where glasses or lamps aren't available; or even if they are, why not use them *lechatchila*? (*besides the fact that I wouldn't feel confident doing just about anything if I couldn't see a thing*)