# Eating at Home and Maarit Ayin

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, meat-and-milk, marit-ayin

Short question: is *maarit ayin* (מראית עין) a problem when one is home alone?

Long question: assuming that [in-vitro meat is pareve](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30438/4504), even if it is maarit ayin to eat it with milk in public, would it be permissible to do so when one is in one's own house and all others present have seen the packaging and know that the IV meat is pareve?

Comment: Why is this different than eating [Morningstar Farms Burgers](https://www.morningstarfarms.com/products/burgers)?

Comment: @DoubleAA that doesn't seem to be relevant because the question assumes that maris ayin applies to this case. Since that premise may be false, the two questions here might not really be one and the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As cited in [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/7461/5323) and [this answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/50974/5323), the gemara says in several places ([Beitzah 9a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=8&daf=9&format=pdf), [Shabbos 64b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=2&daf=64b&format=pdf) and more)

> כל מקום שאסרו חכמים מפני מראית העין - אפילו בחדרי חדרים אסור
>
> Any place that the rabbis forbid something because of מראית עין -- it
>   is forbidden even in the most hidden of rooms

This is also brought down by שלחן ערוך in several places, e.g. [OC 301](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x1507):45.

Comment: Where did the rabbis forbid eating in vitro meat with milk due to מראית עין?

Comment: @DoubleAA "*question: is maarit ayin (מראית עין) a problem when one is home alone?*" + "*However, even if it is considered pareve, one must be aware of potential marit ayin issues, at least until the product becomes widespread.*" (from [an answer](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/30345/5323) to the linked question in the question). .....do you think that second part need be edited in? ....it was kind of assumed by the OP.

Comment: @Shokhet I think the OP's question is clear enough. My question to you stands, though.

Comment: @DoubleAA So my response to you was that I answered the "short question." When I asked about "editing in," I was referring to my answer.