# Shechita Material online

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, internet, slaughter-shochet-shecht

Does anyone have links for Shechita material. Like the pdf of Simla Chadasha translated and pdf of Shechita knife and stones from R' Loike?

Comment: For a start, try the [Simla Chadasha](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37554/5323) in the original Hebrew [from hebrewbooks.org](http://hebrewbooks.org/35269). [Here](https://books.google.com/books?id=U_ImCAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&dq=chaim+loike&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCYQ6AEwAGoVChMIr_Haqcv-xgIVCqseCh3Mpgfs#v=onepage&q=chaim%20loike&f=false) is part of Rabbi Loike's English translation of that sefer (though be warned that it's incomplete)

Comment: Thanks! What about the pdf of the knife and stone guide?

Comment: I'm not sure where you can find that online....there are some pdf guides to *tefisa* (holding the chicken) up  on YUTorah.org; check that out

Comment: [This pdf](http://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/714473/Rabbi_Chaim_Loike/How_to_Hold_the_Chicken_Prior_to_the_Shechitah) is about how to hold the chicken...look at all the other YUTorah stuff from Rabbi Loike; there's a lot of good stuff there `;-)`

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for sharing your question. For more questions about shechita see [here](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/slaughter-shochet-shecht). Consider taking the following brief [tour](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/tour) of the site to learn more. Hope to see you around.

Comment: @Shokhet thanks for that pdf! Still looking for the knife and stone one!

Comment: Also do you know who people got to to get Kabbalah from in the US?

Comment: Actually, Rabbi Loike gives a class. Can you get to YU/Great Neck/Monsey? He'll teach you how to sharpen a knife `:-)`

Comment: Surprisingly, there's a lot of good stuff on Youtube about sharpening shechita knives; make sure to search in both English ("sharpen shechitah knife") and Hebrew ("השחזת סכין השחיטה")

Comment: But where do the guys get kabbalah from?

Comment: I've actually started learning it a bit but now live out of town...

Comment: Is the okay for print the english translation, meaning is it meant for public to use free?

Comment: https://www.yutorah.org/_cdn/_shiurim/holding.pdf -- updated link to pdf

Answer (score 5):

You can buy it [The Art of Crafting the Shechitah Knife and Stone](https://www.lulu.com/en/us/shop/chaim-loike/the-art-of-crafting-the-shechitah-knife-and-stoneeb/ebook/product-1gg9jp8w.html) and a translation of  [Simla Chadasha](https://www.lulu.com/en/us/shop/chaim-loike/soft-cover-simlah-translated/paperback/product-125pwmee.html) both by R Loike on Lulu.

Answer (score 2):

These are recordings of classes of instruction in Shechita in English.

https://www.yutorah.org/search/?teacher=83296&collection=11644