# The concept of shechita and the requirements

Tags: slaughter-shochet-shecht

From where in the Torah does it mention shechita? And where does it mention it must be performed by a Jew? Yes this is a double question.

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/81376/13176 The concept comes from Deut. 12:21 "as I have instructed you" and we also learn out from YOU to mean only a Jew. See link for greater detail.

Comment: Why couldnt you just ask the two separately? And how do you know that only a Jew can perform shehitta?

Comment: @mevaqesh https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81375/why-is-meat-only-kosher-if-a-jew-slaughters-the-animal/81376#81376 answers the second question.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your second question is found at [Why is meat only kosher if a Jew slaughters the animal?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/81375/why-is-meat-only-kosher-if-a-jew-slaughters-the-animal/81376#81376)

The [Rambam Hilchos Shechitah](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/971827/jewish/Shechitah-Chapter-1.htm) gives the mitzvos as

> **Introduction to Hilchos Shechitah**
>
> They contain 5 mitzvot: three positive commandments and two negative
>   commandments. They are:
>
> 1. To slaughter an animal and then to partake of it;
> 2. Not to slaughter an animal and its offspring on the same day;
> 3. To cover the blood of [slaughtered] beasts and fowl;
> 4. Not to take a mother bird together with her young;
> 5. To send away the mother when taking her together with her young.
>
> These mitzvot are explained in the ensuing chapters

He then gives the source of the mitzvos as

> **1**
>
> It is a positive commandment<sup>1</sup> for one who desires to
>   partake of the meat of a domesticated animal, wild beast, or fowl to
>   slaughter [it] and then partake of it,<sup>2</sup> as [Deuteronomy
>   12:21](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9976#v=21) states:
>   "And you shall slaughter from your cattle and from your sheep." And
>   with regard to a firstborn animal with a blemish,<sup>3</sup>
>   [ibid.:22] states: "As one would partake of a deer and a gazelle."
>   From this, we learn that a wild beast is [governed by] the same [laws]
>   as a domesticated animal with regard to ritual slaughter.
>
> And with regard to a fowl, [Leviticus 17:13] states: "that will snare
>   a beast or a fowl as prey... and shed its blood." This teaches that
>   shedding the blood of a fowl is analogous to shedding the blood of a
>   wild beast.<sup>4</sup>
>
> **Footnotes**
>
> <sup>1.</sup> Sefer HaMitzvot (positive commandment 146) and Sefer
>   HaChinuch (mitzvah 451) include this among the 613 mitzvot of the
>   Torah. As mentioned at the beginning of the Mishneh Torah, the Ra'avad
>   differs and does not consider this a mitzvah.
>
> <sup>2.</sup> The Rambam's wording echo his statements in Hilchot
>   Berachot 11:2: "There are other mitzvot that are not obligations, but
>   resemble voluntary activities, for example, the mitzvah of mezuzah....
>   A person is not obligated to dwell in a house that requires a mezuzah
>   in order to fulfill this mitzvah." Similarly, in the instance at hand,
>   a person is not obligated to slaughter. If, however, he desires to eat
>   meat, he must fulfill this mitzvah.
>
> <sup>3.</sup> Note the Kessef Mishneh who elaborates, explaining that
>   although Rashi does not interpret the verse in the same manner the
>   Rambam does, there is support for the Rambam's interpretation.
>
> <sup>4.</sup> I.e., in both instances, ritual slaughter is required.
>   The Kessef Mishneh notes that Chulin 27b derives this equivalence from
>   another source and explains why the Rambam cites this verse instead.