# Does killing a pest make a person unclean?

Tags: halacha, death, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, bugs

I know there were previous questions asking whether it is OK to kill a pest, say a fly, but the consequences are unclear. So I'm asking if killing a pest makes a person unclean.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya.  Question:  Assuming that everyone is tamei at the present time (for numerous reasons), how can anything make it worse?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8513/does-an-improperly-slaughtered-animal-render-the-shochet-impure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Leviticus 11:29](http://bible.ort.org/books/pentd2.asp?ACTION=displaypage&BOOK=3&CHAPTER=11). Animals that walk on four paws, with their bodies clearly high off the ground (e.g. a dog or cat), have carcasses that would make you "ritually impure." The only smaller animals with this property are the seven "creepy-crawlies" listed there, e.g. a mole or mouse. So if you killed a mole or mouse *and then touched it* (or touched a dead mouse that died on its own, for that matter), you'd be "ritually impure." (All you'd have to do to fix that status, however, is immerse in a ritual bath and wait until nightfall.)

However this is a moot point today as we assume we're all ritually impure, and we don't deal with laws (e.g. Temple stuff) that require a state of "purity." Contact with a human corpse makes you a lot more "ritually impure" than contact with a dead mouse, and yet those who are involved in Jewish burial societies are held in very high regard. The whole "ritual purity" thing is limited to certain laws. (Note that a kohen is still prohibited from touching a human corpse today, but can touch dead critters all he likes.)

A dead bug, however, wouldn't even cause a state of ritual impurity.