# Was there an alert system in place in the Mikdash for cases of an invalid shechita creating tum'as neveila?

Tags: beis-hamikdash, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, slaughter-shochet-shecht, kodshim

Was there a טומאה alert/lockdown system in the מקדש mentioned in Shas or anywhere else?

Each בהמה that was sacrificed would carry an inherent risk of טומאת נבלה if something went wrong with the *shechita* *(eg. one of the five פסולי שחיטה mentioned in מסכת חולין)*.  The animal carcass would become an אב הטומאה and wreak havoc among all the surrounding *kodshim* which are susceptible to becoming invalid even as a רביעי לטומאה. This is not to mention all the *kohanim* and others who would be at risk of becoming *tamei* and imparting טומאה to *kodshim*. To make things a little more complicated, the carcass would have טומאת משא (unlike a dead שרץ) which would make its removal more difficult and complicated since one couldn't simply carry it out of the *mikdash* via indirect contact with another object being *mafsik*.

Even if one were to conjecture that *shochtim* were specially trained and prepared and the risk was small, the issue would especially be compounded during *regalim* where there were thousands of *korbanos* going on.

Was also wondering whether there was some sort of miracle that limited שחיטה פסולה in the *mikdash*, but this isn't listed among the 10 miracles in [Pirkei Avos 5:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Pirkei_Avot.5.5).

Comment: See Shabbos 114b regarding alerts not being required for Kohanim and Chulin 123a regarding Shechitah and Beitzah 18a regarding purity in general  - כהנים זריזים הם, and Yevamos 90a - הציץ מרצה על הטומאה

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8513/does-an-improperly-slaughtered-animal-render-the-shochet-impure

Comment: Thanks שלום - now I have some homework for later.  Menachem - the mishna in Eiruvin referenced in that earlier Mi Yodeya question definitely is a step in the right direction since it deals with tuma contingency plans in the mikdash.  Since that was a sheretz (I just fleshed out my original question re: this aspect), things are a bit less complicated there since only tumas maga. Plus (I could be wrong here), but I would guess that especially on a regel, a pasul shechita situation would be more likely than finding a dead sheretz.

Comment: @שלום - al acharon rishon re: הציץ מרצה על הטומאה - doesn't all that accomplish is a situational acceptance of korbanos brought b'tuma but doesn't actually remove the tuma - and would not preclude the need to remove the dead beheima to avoid further tuma? Also could get into טומאה הותרה\דחויה בציבור but that's not an ideal situation.

Comment: They had a [Psykter](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%A0%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%94_%D7%94)

Comment: I'm imagining a siren and flashing red lights all over the place in the 3rd BH